# Why is CLLocation's Vertical Accuracy better than it's Horizontal Accuracy?

Tags: ios, ios7, gps, cllocation

The iOS's vertical accuracy is stated as +/- 3 m, while it's horizontal is +/- 5m.  I believe the horizontal accuracy, but the vertical is WAY OFF.  Any ideas?  If Apple is providing an accuracy value, why isn't it realistic?  I'm getting +/- hundreds of meters in the vertical direction.

Comment: Bear in mind that vertical position is relative to sea level, not to the ground.

Comment: Are you saying that the vertical accuracy value is +/- 3m but the reported vertical position is wrong by several hundred meters? or that sometimes the vertical accuracy value is +/- hundred of meters?

Comment: I'm saying that CLLocation is saying the accuracy is +/- 3 m, but the accuracy I am getting is nowhere near that good.  I get swings of hundreds of meters. (sampling at 1 Hz)

Comment: Are you using your own code to work with CLLocation? When you are flying, where do you have the phone?

Answer (score 0):

First you know that vertcial means "height above sea level".
(I know some persosns who beleived it means the y Achsis so wrongly assumed its means latitude)

Second: Move out of your house.
Inside sitting near the window, GPS will not work well.

vertical position (altitude) needs one more satellite in view (at least 4), so is not always reliable if GPS sees only 3 satelites.
However if the position was delivered by GPS then altitude should not be off by some hundered meters. Although it may happen once in a day.

Make sure the altitude was delivered by GPS (I am not 100% sure if altitude may also be set by alternative location technics (Wlan) and how apple handles this, but if you have a valid speed or course value then the position is reported by GPS, and in that case the altitude should not be off by some hundred meters)

vertical accuracy of +-3m is for sure not true, where do you get such wrong information?

generally for GPS receivers the horicontal accuracy is twice good as vertical.
So expect 10m in vertical and about 3-5 in horicontal.

Comment: 1) Yes, I know what vertical means.

2) I am not in my house. I am out flying.

3) I understand how GPS works, and I know the vertical channel is not as good as the horizontal one.

4) The "Wrong information" comes from Apple's CLLocation object which states that the vertical accuracy is <3-5m.

5) I have a WHOLE bunch of data showing it varying by hundreds of meters between samples which come in at 1Hz.

Comment: Which device? iPhone3 is known to have a worse GPS than iPhone4+

Comment: The vertical acc in the CLLocation Object is the estimated(!) vertical accuracy. So an estimation without any garuantees.